# Will CompassGps roll back if the transaction is rolled back?

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, lucene, compass-lucene

If CompassGps mirroring is used with Hibernate, what happens if the database transaction rolls back? Will the changes to the index be rolled back (assuming file store for the index)?

It seems like if the Lucene index is stored on the disk it won't be automatically rolled back, unless Compass is smart enough to handle that for you.

FWIW, I am using the Searchable plugin with Grails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wouldn't be anything to roll back on the Compass/Lucene end. Compass registers event listeners and acts on inserts, deletes and updates to update the Lucene index. If a transaction rolled back then Compass wouldn't get those events.

Comment: So Compass is only notified when/if a transaction commits successfully?

Comment: There's not a lot of technical detail here but this section of the docs describes the integration: http://www.compass-project.org/docs/2.1.4/reference/html/gps-hibernate.html